# A single word for "table of contents" and "table of figures"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word (including compound nouns, of course) to describe table of contents, table of figures, and table of objects? (Table of objects is very similar to table of figures, but they are not the same.)

Comment: @jsv - Please tell us how you plan to use this term and why “front matter” (which certainly encompasses these tables) is too broad for your use.

Answer (score 1):

These are **front matter** or **preliminaries**.

My battered *Chicago Manual of Style* (13th Ed.) says in 1.1:

> A book usually consists of three major division: (1) the *front matter* or *preliminaries* ...

It goes on to list out the preliminaries:

- Book half title
- Series title
- Title page
- Copyright notice
- Dedication
- blank
- Table of contents
- Table of illustrations
- List of tables
- (more)